# send custom mail makes memory leaks in python loop?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I think this question is not good for understand, but i have to guess about it.

Status:

- send mail for over then 20,000 users.
- send mail that has custom html for every users.
- mail will be sent on production Server.

I expect, memory usage will be bigger then usual and if i use orm as on, query count will be over then 20,000 count.
so i planed this work like this.

1. get Queryset on database on start. then, make this to `dict()` with only using data. that `dict()` call `queryset`
2. Every Users has filtered data which name is `dataset`.

so code will be like this.

```
for user in every_user:
    filter = user.get_filter()
    dataset = {k: v for k, v in queryset.iteritems() if v['status'] == filter}
    message_html = render_to_string('a.html', dataset)
    send_mail(user.email, message_html)
```

so, i am worry about `dataset` and `message_html` are use memory and, it will make memory leaks (i think..).

so this is question. i have to `del dataset` and `del message_html` on that `for` loop?

Comment: Have you considered using some mass-mailing tool (like campaign monitor etc) instead ?

Comment: i considered about that kind of  tool, but customizing for all email was too hard. can you suggest any kind of tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses garbage collection. That means that when a variable has no references on it, it *can* be freed by the garbage collector. `del` does not free memory: it just remove the indentifier pointing to the actual variable.

Example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
del a
```

b still points to the list [1,2,3], so it cannot be freed

That means that as `dataset` and `message_html` and defined inside the loop they are automatically undefined at the end of each iteration, so `del dataset` and `del message_html` is essentially no-op. It just causes an explicit destruction of the identifiers that will be implicitely destroyed on next instruction

TL/DR: in your code `del dataset` and `del message_html` on end of loop would be no-op.

For the actual question, in your code, Python will only use memory for one single user and free it before next user iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Given the example code, those variables will be garbage collected. There is no need to free them.

If you're nervous, you could simply split the contents of the loop into a function taking the user as a parameter. It is easy to reason that a local variable within a function that is never passed out of the function necessarily is available for garbage collection as soon as the function returns.